# Dashboard for Spring Tool Suite (STS) has strange charset after initial install

Tags: spring-tool-suite

After installing STS 3.8.1 on my Mac (OS X El Capitan) the Dashboard had some funky/unreadable characters.  How do I change/fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the underlying reason for this is a JavaFX font rendering issue (we use the JavaFX webkit-based webview for the dashboard). We are working on a fix for this (related bug is https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4422). In the meantime I would suggest to switch to the old dashboard (you can do that in the Preferences -> Spring -> Dashboard).

Comment: Thank you Martin.  I switched to the old dashboard and all is well now!

Comment: This solution may create an infinite loop if no Roo distributions are installed. After changing to the old Dashboard in Spring STS v3.8.3, I got a pop-up saying "You are trying to generate an [SIC] Spring Roo project, but you don't have any Spring Roo distribution installed. Include some Spring Roo distribution before continue." after clicking Ok (only choice) a Roo Support dialog appears. If I cancel, because I don't have Roo, it takes me back to the initial alert. Seems that the only way to break this infinite loop will be to install Roo, which I don't want or need.

Comment: Thanks for the information LightDye, I'll check this issue ASAP. Regards.

Comment: Hi again, I've just create the following pull-request that fixes the infinite loop problem. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/pull/92 Hope it helps.